# Property VS reference: share a variable between class methods

Tags: php, oop

Let's say that I'm building a class (for a generic purpose) and I have two methods that work on common variables.

```
class renderElement
{
    public function process()
    {
        $output = array();
        $data = $this->supportMethod($output);
        // do stuff with $output
    }

    public function supportMethod(&$processed_output)
    {
        // do stuff with $processed_output
    }
}
```

I want to use the same variable into both methods; let's say *$output*.

I'm curious to know the theory behind the choice of eventually rely on a class property (like following) or when instead is ok (or better) to pass the variable as reference.

```
class renderElement
{
    private $output = array();

    public function process()
    {
        $data = $this->supportMethod();
        // do stuff with $this->output
    }

    public function supportMethod()
    {
        // do stuff with $this->output
    }
}
```

Advantages? Disadvantages? Design suggestions?
Suggested lectures about this kind of design choices?

**[ EDIT ]**

I would add that the variable/property should obviously have sense as an object property. I'm not talking about variables for just supporting data processing.

Comment: `$data = $this->supportMethod(&$output);`?!? Call time pass by reference is deprecated

Comment: @user2864740 you are right; messed with copy/paste/change :)

Comment: @MarkBaker oh right I forgot it (I didn't go much deep into the reasons). I should define it by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object fundamentally consists of two things, behaviour and state.

Methods of your class define the behaviour of your object.

Attributes of your class define the state of your object.

In your first example, `$output` isn't a part of the object's state, so it will not persist throughout the life of the object.

In your second example, `$output` will persist throughout the life of the object since it is a part of the object's state.

Take this example...

```
class Shape 
{    
    protected $sides;

    public function getNumberOfSides() 
    {
        return $this->sides;
    }
}

class Triangle extends Shape 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->sides = 3;
    }
}

class Square extends Shape 
{    
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->sides = 4;
    }
}

$shape = new Square;
echo $shape->getNumberOfSides(); // Returns 4

$shape = new Triangle;
echo $shape->getNumberOfSides(); // Returns 3
```

`$sides` (number of sides) is an intrinsic part of a shapes nature, therefore it is appropriate for it to be a part of the object's state throughout the life of the object. This doesn't really have anything to do with the convenience of passing parameters between methods in the same class.

Comment: I think this is a good start and hits upon the "core" issue. However, I think the last paragraphs (and when either/or approach may be more appropriate) could be expanded upon, even to the point of seeming redundant.

Comment: That is, I agree that passing a reference is *no different* than passing any value to a method (excepting mutations wrt the caller) and a separate concept from acting directly upon a property within the method. The latter form (which uses "this" and "the property") ties the method strongly to the state of the instance, while the former does not and the method could be an adhoc function as long as it exhibited the same behavior.

Comment: Agree. Passing by reference appears to be a bit of a red herring in the OP.